# C# Linq Select Rows Where ID Equals ID in CSV

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, csv

What I have is a string of comma separated IDs that I'm receiving from a query string (e.g. 23,51,6,87,29). Alternately, that string could just say "all".

In my Linq query I need a way to say (in pseudo code):

```
from l in List<>
    where l.Id = all_of_the_ids_in_csv
    && other conditions
select new {...}
```

I'm just not sure how to go about doing that. I'm not even sure what to google to get me going in the right direction. Any pointing in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to split your query in 2 - first part will select by ID, and the select one will select *other conditions*.

First of all: check if query string contains numbers, or is *just `all`*:

```
var IEnumerable<ListItemType> query = sourceList;

if(queryStringValue != "All")
{
    var ids = queryStringValue.Split(new[] { ',' })
                              .Select(x => int.Parse(x)) // remove that line id item.Id is a string
                              .ToArray();

    query = query.Where(item => ids.Contains(item.Id));
}

from l in query
    // other conditions
select new {...}
```

Because LINQ queries have deffered execution you can build queries like that without performance drawback. Query won't be executed until you ask for results (by `ToList` call or enumeration).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want it with just one LINQ query:

```
var idArray = all_of_the_ids_in_csv.Split(',');
from l in List<>
    where (all_of_the_ids_in_csv == "All" || idArray.Contains(l.Id))
    && other conditions
select new {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is using `string.Split`

```
var ids = string.split(rawIdString, ",").ToList();
var objects = ids.Where(id=> /*filter id here */).Select(id=>new { /* id will be the single id from the csv */ }); 
// at this point objects will be an IEnumerable<T> where T is whatever type you created in the new statement above
```